# How do I know eggs are fresh?

Tags: eggs, fresh

I buy eggs from market last week and when I used their colours are little bit changed.I am confused that eggs are fresh or not.

Answer (score -1):

the color does not signify freshness. rather it changes based on the diet of the chickens.
you can see freshness based on the firmness of that little sack around the yolk